# Flutter iOS build Failed with Multiple commands produce error

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

This issue is raised by many, but their issue is solved by using one of the two methods shown here : [Flutter iOS build failure error with Multiple commands after the Xcode upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399115/11718292)

**But, neither could solve my issue.**

The error :

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                            5.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    error: Multiple commands produce '/Users/femindharamshi/Downloads/RotiBankProject-Master(Build excluded)/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework':
    1) Target 'Runner' has copy command from '/Users/femindharamshi/Downloads/RotiBankProject-Master(Build excluded)/ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework' to '/Users/femindharamshi/Downloads/RotiBankProject-Master(Build excluded)/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework'
    2) That command depends on command in Target 'Runner': script phase “[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks”
    warning: ignoring duplicated output file: '/Users/femindharamshi/Downloads/RotiBankProject-Master(Build excluded)/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Frameworks/Flutter.framework' in shell script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks'. This warning represents an extremely serious project misconfiguration and will likely cause some shell scripts in your project to be skipped entirely, leading to other build failures or missing files in the build directory. This will be a hard error in the future. (in target 'Runner')
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

**After trying the first solution :**

-> Changing to **Legacy Build Mode** and then cleaning the project in XCode as well as Android Studio using flutter clean

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
[{"event":"app.progress","params":{"appId":"8c12fe6e-8dad-4659-864a-f3cd80a29844","id":"0","progressId":null,"message":"Running pod install..."}}]Running pod install...

Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           31.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:59:20: warning: unused variable 'fileName' [-Wunused-variable]
            NSString * fileName=@"";
                       ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:108:17: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    _result(fileName);
                    ^
                    self->
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:115:13: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                _result(fileName);
                ^
                self->
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:89:35: warning: unused variable 'assetChangeRequest' [-Wunused-variable]
        __block PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = nil;
                                      ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:15:18: warning: unused variable 'SOURCE_CAMERA' [-Wunused-const-variable]
    static const int SOURCE_CAMERA = 0;
                     ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:16:18: warning: unused variable 'SOURCE_GALLERY' [-Wunused-const-variable]
    static const int SOURCE_GALLERY = 1;
                     ^
    6 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:19:23: warning: unused variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
        UIViewController *viewController =
                          ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:70:21: warning: unused variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                        ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:71:21: warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                        ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:48:19: warning: unused variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
            NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                      ^
    8 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    4 warnings generated.
    === BUILD TARGET Runner OF PROJECT Runner WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===
    /* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
    /Users/femindharamshi/Downloads/RotiBankProject-Master(Build excluded)/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard: error: Interface Builder could not open the document Main.storyboard" because it does not exist.
    /* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
    /Users/femindharamshi/Downloads/RotiBankProject-Master(Build excluded)/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard: error: Interface Builder could not open the document LaunchScreen.storyboard" because it does not exist.

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

**Trying option 2 : **

-> Using new Build System, Deleted the Flutter.framework from Embedded Frameworks in Build Phases, and did a flutter clean.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           28.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:59:20: warning: unused variable 'fileName' [-Wunused-variable]
            NSString * fileName=@"";
                       ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:108:17: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    _result(fileName);
                    ^
                    self->
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:115:13: warning: block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                _result(fileName);
                ^
                self->
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:89:35: warning: unused variable 'assetChangeRequest' [-Wunused-variable]
        __block PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = nil;
                                      ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:15:18: warning: unused variable 'SOURCE_CAMERA' [-Wunused-const-variable]
    static const int SOURCE_CAMERA = 0;
                     ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/image_saver-1.0.0/ios/Classes/ImageSaverPlugin.m:16:18: warning: unused variable 'SOURCE_GALLERY' [-Wunused-const-variable]
    static const int SOURCE_GALLERY = 1;
                     ^
    6 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    4 warnings generated.
    In file included from /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param sharedStyle
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter 'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean 'tapToDismissEnabled'?
     @param allowTapToDismiss
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            tapToDismissEnabled
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
     @param queueEnabled
     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:19:23: warning: unused variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
        UIViewController *viewController =
                          ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:70:21: warning: unused variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                        ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:71:21: warning: unused variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
                CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                        ^
    /Applications/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.2/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:48:19: warning: unused variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
            NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                      ^
    8 warnings generated.
    error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/femindharamshi/Downloads/RotiBankProject-Master(Build excluded)/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard'
    error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/femindharamshi/Downloads/RotiBankProject-Master(Build excluded)/ios/Runner/Base.lproj/LaunchScreen.storyboard'
    note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build description

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

So now, how do i fix this error ?

Comment: Did you find a a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue could be resolved by migrating your Xcode project, see [this GitHub post](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20685#issuecomment-542322890) for reference.

> If you're still seeing this error, you will need to migrate your Xcode
> project:
>
> 1. File > Workspace Settings... > Build System, change dropdown to New Build System (Default)
> 2. In your Podfile, add the line
>
> `install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true`
>
> See
> https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/platform_view/ios/Podfile
> for example.
> 3. Run `flutter build ios`