# ios build error: Multiple commands produce on "flutter run" from command line

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

i am facing an issue while running my flutter app for ios.
Everything works fine when i try to build from Xcode, But when i try to run using

> flutter run

from the command line i get the below error.

> error: Multiple commands produce
> '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex/Shaw Academy':
> 1) Target 'NotificationService' has link command with output
> '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex/Shaw Academy'
> 2) Target 'NotificationViewController' has link command with output
> '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex/Shaw Academy'
> error: Multiple commands produce
> '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex':
> 1) Target 'NotificationService' has create directory command with output
> '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex'
> 2) Target 'NotificationViewController' has create directory command with output
> '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex'
> note: Using new build systemnote: Planning buildnote: Constructing build descriptionwarning: Mapping
> architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build
> settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'in_app_purchase' from
> project 'Pods')warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and
> Valid Architectures build settings are configured correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target
> 'in_app_purchase' from project 'Pods')warning: duplicate output file
> '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex/_CodeSignature' on task: CodeSign
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex (in target 'NotificationViewController' from project 'Runner')warning: duplicate output
> file '' on task: CodeSign
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex (in target 'NotificationViewController' from project 'Runner')warning: duplicate output
> file '' on task: CopySwiftLibs
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex (in target 'NotificationViewController' from project 'Runner')warning: duplicate output
> file '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex/Shaw Academy' on task: Ld
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex/Shaw Academy normal x86_64 (in target 'NotificationViewController' from project
> 'Runner')warning: duplicate output file '' on task: Ld
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex/Shaw Academy normal x86_64 (in target 'NotificationViewController' from project
> 'Runner')warning: duplicate output file
> '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex' on task: MkDir
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex (in target 'NotificationViewController' from project 'Runner')warning: duplicate output
> file '' on task: MkDir
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex (in target 'NotificationViewController' from project 'Runner')warning: duplicate output
> file '/Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex/Info.plist' on task: ProcessInfoPlistFile
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex/Info.plist
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/ios/NotificationViewController/Info.plist
> (in
> target 'NotificationViewController' from project 'Runner')warning: duplicate output file '' on task:
> RegisterExecutionPolicyException
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex (in target 'NotificationViewController' from project 'Runner')warning: duplicate output
> file '' on task: Touch
> /Users/lohithkumar/Documents/GitHub/shaw_mobile_app_flutter/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shaw
> Academy.appex (in target 'NotificationViewController' from project 'Runner')
>
> Could not build the application for the simulator. Error launching
> application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.

Can anyone help me on this please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter iOS build failure error with Multiple commands after the Xcode upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398521/flutter-ios-build-failure-error-with-multiple-commands-after-the-xcode-upgrade)

Comment: @Daniil i don't see the flutter.framework inside the embedded frameworks