# Xcode 13.2.1: Multiple commands produce problem

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I ran my app on simulator and everything works fine but I keep getting this error on flutter build ipa. Pls anyone help with how to fix it?? I think this is caused by ImageNotification extension.

Error (Xcode): Multiple commands produce
'/Users/hiidee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-afelnukxgwdlvvdqgngpnpmsfmoc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':

1. Target 'GoogleUtilities-00567490' has create directory command with output
   '/Users/hiidee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-afelnukxgwdlvvdqgngpnpmsfmoc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
2. Target 'GoogleUtilities-54e75ca4' has create directory command with output
   '/Users/hiidee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-afelnukxgwdlvvdqgngpnpmsfmoc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Runner/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'

Encountered error while archiving for device.

Comment: Did you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52398521/flutter-ios-build-failure-error-with-multiple-commands-after-the-xcode-upgrade#answer-66985464 ?

Comment: None of the issues worked for me. But i just found it that the line pod 'GoogleUtilities' is missing from my podfile in ios. I added that and the build is successful.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer here

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve it by adding below line to my podfile inside ios folder

```
pod 'GoogleUtilities'
```

Comment: can you please explain how you solve this issue exactly, can you post your podfile as a sample or example?